# Lubuntu 16.04.2 LTS - Dual monitors, two desktops

Tags: lubuntu, multiple-monitors

I am using Lubuntu 16.04.2 lts with dual monitors. It works fine but I would like to have different desktop on left monitor (desktop 1) and different desktop on right monitor (desktop 2). I cant find out how to do that, second monitor behaves always like an extension of the same desktop of the first monitor. Is it possible to do that in lubuntu or is this option available only in ubuntu "heavier" versions, like kubuntu? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try installing arandr, it's a screen layout editor. A standard install of Lubuntu doesn't have an app for organising multiple monitors (although I'm sure there are command line options).