# Display Settings / Dual Displays > Lubuntu 20.04

Tags: lubuntu, display

Are there dedicated display settings within Lubuntu like there are with Ubuntu?

I was about to install Lubuntu, but couldn't get my dual monitors to work. I couldn't find any display settings.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lubuntu 16.04.2 LTS - Dual monitors, two desktops](https://askubuntu.com/questions/931514/lubuntu-16-04-2-lts-dual-monitors-two-desktops)

Comment: Thanks for the reply @dlin. I attempted to go that route before posting this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open **Application menu**, then

1. *preferences*
2. *lxqt setting*
3. *open lxqt configuration center*

Then on configuration center you will see monitor setting or you can simply open application menu and type monitor setting on search.

Comment: Thank you @electron! This worked perfectly.